# MySQL give a rank to each group

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What I'm trying to do is update all rows column with the same `id` with increasing number and when there is no more of this `id` I to go on the next one.

**Table:**

```
id  column
1   0
1   0
2   0
2   0
3   0
3   0
```

**I tried:**

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE table SET column = @i:=@i+1
```

This way I updated the column but the column values goes like `1 2 3 4 5 6` and 
I must reset the `@i` back to 0 everytime when `id` of the row has changed.
**OR:**

**Table:**

```
id  column
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
```

I guess this should be made by a loop. But can't get it. Plus when I tried to make a loop in the MySQL (PHPMyAdmin), it gave me an error. What I read around is that I can't make loops directly in the PHPMyAdmin or I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table ,(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curCol := '') r SET column=
    ( CASE id WHEN @curCol  THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1  ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curCol := id END)
```

[Test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d4de5/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! All fine now :) Why is that `r` there? Is it about `recursive` or something ? I am sorry about the pathetic question.

Comment: @TomaTomov Every subquery needs an alias,that r could be anything.