# MySQL dense rank for each group/partition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions, dense-rank

I am trying to build a dense rank kind of functionality but not exactly dense rank. I want to rank each group but within each group I want to keep the rank same for same values. I've written the following query which gives me a dense rank kind of functionality

```
SELECT  id, item_code
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM table t, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE <several filters>
```

[image]

Whereas, I want this

[image]

The closest question I found is this one [MySQL give a rank to each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058132/mysql-give-a-rank-to-each-group)

Please help.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, and is there any chance of upgrading to MySQL 8+ if you are not already using it?

Comment: Also, for the `1803` id group, why does `131677` rank before `33373`?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using version and there is a possibility to move to 8 but not confirmed. I know ver 8 has rank function. Secondly, order of item_code column doesn't matter as the code is not always numeric

Answer (score 3):

You can create a (temporary) *MyISAM* table with an AUTO_INCREMENT `rank` column in a composite PRIMARY KEY. This way `rank` will have one sequence per `ID` when you fill the table with distinct `(id, item_code)` combinations. You can then join that table with the original data.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_rank(
  id INT,
  item_code varchar(50),
  rank INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, rank)
) engine=MyISAM
  SELECT DISTINCT NULL as rank, id, item_code
  FROM test t
  -- WHERE <several filters>
  ORDER BY id, item_code
;

SELECT t.*, x.rank
FROM tmp_rank x
JOIN test t USING(id, item_code)
-- WHERE <several filters>
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXjbAiKrmqYia4dzK4nHa7/0)

If you want it in a single query, you can try this one:

```
SELECT id, item_code,
    CASE 
      WHEN id = @curId AND item_code = @curCode
        THEN @curRank
      WHEN id <> @curId THEN @curRank := 1
      ELSE @curRank := @curRank + 1
    END  AS rank,
    @curId := id,
    @curCode := item_code
FROM test t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT
    @curRank := 0,
    cast(@curCode := null as signed),
    cast(@curId   := NULL as char)
) r
#WHERE <several filters>
ORDER BY id, item_code
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrCfzz7yEwTrxoXZqAf4wA/0)

Be aware, that the evaluation order of operations in an SQL statement is not defined. So when you read and write a user variable in the same statement, you relay on implementation details.

In *MySQL 8* or *MariaDB 10.2* it would be:

```
SELECT  id, item_code,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY item_code) as `rank`
FROM test t
-- WHERE <several filters>
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hZeMpNdjrj1PwWRHdHFjU7/0)

Comment: In the original posted question, I am trying to reset the rank back to 1 for each group. You solution is incrementing the rank which is exactly what dense rank does but my requirement is a bit different. Please see the second image in the question.

Comment: @Ali - You can use Barmar's code. It works with a small fix.

Answer (score 2):

The correct method using variables is:

```
SELECT id,item_code,
       (@rn := if(@id = id,
                  if(@ic = item_code, @rn,  -- do not increment
                     if(@ic := item_code, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                    ),
                  if(@id := id,
                     if(@ic := @item_code, 1, 1                        
                       ), 1
                     if(@ic := @item_code, 1, 1                        
                       )
                    )
                 )                         
       ) as dense_rank
FROM table t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @id := '', @ic := '') params
WHERE <several filters>
ORDER BY item_code;
```

Two things:

- Assigning a variable in one expression and using it in another can lead to issues.  You need to assign and use the variables in a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.
- The `ORDER BY` is really important.

You can also express this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id, item_code
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_code)
         FROM table t2
         WHERE . . . AND
               t2.item_code <= t.item_code
        ) as rank
FROM table t
WHERE <several filters>
```

Comment: The first solution works but it keeps increment the rank for each group. What I originally asked for was that I want to reset the rank to 1 for each group as shown in the second image where rank for each group starts from 1.

Comment: @Ali . . . I misread the results.  That makes the logic a bit more complicated, but still doable with variables.

Comment: Tried but getting an error - 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `if(@id := id, if(@ic := @it' at line 4`

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `@cur_rank` only when the `item_code` changes, and set it back to `1` when the `id` changes.

```
SELECT  id, item_code,
    @curRank := IF(@curId = id, 
                    IF(@curItem = item_code, @curRank, @curRank + 1),
                    1) AS rank,
    @curId := id, @curItem := item_code
FROM table t, (SELECT @curRank := 0, @curId := 0, @curItem := null) r
WHERE <several filters>
ORDER BY id, item_code
```

Comment: `@curItem = item_code` should be `@curItem := item_code` at the end of the SELECT clause.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't see the difference.

Comment: `=` (compare) and `:=` (set)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel 

Comment: @Barmar it return 1 as rank for every row

Comment: Can you post data in text form? I can't paste an image into dbfiddle.